# Filling 2D Array with 2 values from a random list (2048 Game)

Tags: java, arrays, 2048

I am trying to recreate the 2048 game and I have hit a brick wall and am stumped. I have made my grid with a 2d array and it seems to be working okay. I have then made a method to store an list of empty/free space in this grid/array so that the two starting numbers can be assigned to two random free spaces. My problem is that I cannot get the numbers to show inside the actual grid. I have my code below and would appreciate if anybody could show me where i am going wrong. Apologies if I explained this horribly, I am still quite new to Java.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    //Game Board Size Method - Getting User Number to use for dimension of game board
    public static int gameBoardSize() {
        int number = 0;
        int row = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to 1024");
        System.out.print("Please select a number between 4 & 8 to determine the size of your game board: "); //Prompt user to select number
        number = in.nextInt(); //Storing number in variable
        if (number >= 4 && number <= 8) { //If number is >= 4 and <= 8
            row = number; //Assign number to row variable
        } else {
            System.out.print("Error, please select a number between 4 & 8"); //Error print message
        }
        return row; //Return
    }

    //Display Game board method - Array for game board grid and to display the grid.
    public static void displayGameBoard(int[][] gameBoard, int gameBoardSize) {
        String divider;
        switch (gameBoardSize) {
            case 5:
                divider = "\n+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+"; //User Number 5
                break;
            case 6:
                divider = "\n+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+"; //User Number 6
                break;
            case 7:
                divider = "\n+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+"; //User Number 7
                break;
            case 8:
                divider = "\n+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+"; //User Number 8
                break;
            default:
                divider = "\n+----+-----+-----+----+"; //User Number 4
        }
        System.out.println(divider); //Printing Divider at top
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard[i].length; j++) {
                if (gameBoard[i][j] == 0) { //If both i & j is == 0
                    System.out.print("|     "); //Print this left border
                }
                if (j == gameBoard[j].length - 1) { //If 2nd array length -1 (end)
                    System.out.print("|"); //Print end border
                }
            }

            System.out.println(divider); //Printing Divider at bottom
        }
    }



    public static int[][] createGameBoard(int userRows) {
        return new int[userRows][userRows]; //Returning rows
    }


    //Method to loop through array to find empty space
    public static int[][] findEmptyCells(int[][] gameBoard)  {
        int freeCellCount = 0;
        int[][] emptyList = new int[gameBoard.length * gameBoard.length][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard[i].length; j++) {
                if (gameBoard[i][j] == 0) {
                    emptyList[freeCellCount][0] = i;
                    emptyList[freeCellCount][1] = j;
                    freeCellCount++;
                }
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int rndPair = rnd.nextInt(freeCellCount);
                emptyList[rndPair][0] = i;
                emptyList[rndPair][1] = j;
            }
        }
        return emptyList;
    }

    //Use WASD: W for up, S for Down, A for Left and D for Right
    public static void instructions() {
        System.out.println("How to Play");
        System.out.println("Press W to move up");
        System.out.println("Press S to move down");
        System.out.println("Press A to move left");
        System.out.println("Press D to move right");
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = gameBoardSize();
        int[][] gameBoard = createGameBoard(rows);
        displayGameBoard(gameBoard, rows);
        instructions();
        int[][] findEmptyCells = findEmptyCells(gameBoard);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are **required** to create this game using printing to the console - I would abandon this method ASAP. Creating a game like 2048 in a space that is not designed to act like an animation pane is going to be very difficult and frustrating.

Instead, I would have each tile be an object and do some research on swing and Graphics in Java.

If you must do it this way, (by the way, check the way you set up the grid - it's not consistent spacing) you'll have to print the values between the "|" characters.

**What's a smart way to do that?** Well, you could create a 2D int array, `int[][]`, and store all the values on the game board. Then, you can loop over every element in the 2D array, and print it between your "|" characters. **This example below will work for any size 2D array. Try changing the number of values you pass in and notice how it behaves**.

```
public class Test {
    private static int[][] temp = new int[][] {{0,2, 4},{4, 4,16}, {3, 0, 128}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = temp.length;
        int cols = temp[0].length;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            // This will resize our row separator for each row
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                System.out.print("+-----");
            }

            System.out.print("+\n");

            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                System.out.print("|");

                // Here you have to deal with the spacing. You can see that this is ugly.
                // There's definitely better ways to do this, such as using mod
                if (temp[i][j] == 0) {System.out.print("     ");}
                else if (temp[i][j] < 10) {System.out.print("  " + temp[i][j] + "  ");}
                else if (temp[i][j] < 100) {System.out.print("  " + temp[i][j] + " ");}
                else if (temp[i][j] < 1000) {System.out.print(" " + temp[i][j] + " ");}
            }

            System.out.print("|\n");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            System.out.print("+-----");
        }

        System.out.print("+\n");
    }
}
```

Output from the program above:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |  2  |  4  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  4  |  4  |  16 |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  3  |     | 128 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

But then there is the problem of keeping your spacing correct. You need to account for the length of the number, because your have to have the right number of spaces printed if the number is blank. Or you'll have to use replace()... it sounds confusing.

Comment: Token, thank you for the reply. Unfortunately i am required to create this using the print console. I know my spacing is only for the size of a blank cell. I cannot figure out how to get a number to print inside my grid/cells at the moment so i cannot fix my sizing issue just yet. Thank you for the reply and i will test your code out for sure.

Answer (score 1):

To piggy back off @sleepToken's answer you can use `String.format` to pad your output:

```
public class Test {
  private static int[][] temp = new int[][] {{0,2, 4},{4, 4,16}, {3, 0, 128}};

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int rows = temp.length;
      int cols = temp[0].length;

      String separator = "+---------------";

      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
          // This will resize our row separator for each row
          for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
              System.out.print(separator);
          }

          System.out.print("+\n");

          for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            System.out.print(String.format("|%5s%5s%5s", "", temp[i][j], ""));
          }

          System.out.print("|\n");
      }

      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        System.out.print(separator);
      }

      System.out.print("+\n");
  }
}
```

Which will pad like thus:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|         0     |         2     |         4     |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|         4     |         4     |        16     |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|         3     |         0     |       128     |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Might have to play around with the padding values but the format that i have will play nicely up to a 5 digit number.

Below is another example of how you can do dynamic padding based of how long you want your max cell width (length) to be:

```
public class Test {
  private static int[][] temp = new int[][] {{0,2, 4},{4, 4,16}, {3, 0, 8}};

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rows = temp.length;
    int cols = temp[0].length;

    int maxCellLength = 15; //define our cell width

    int longestDigit = longestDigit(temp); //get the length of our longest diget

    if (longestDigit > maxCellLength) maxCellLength = longestDigit + 10; //add extra padding if the longest digit is longer than our cell length

    int leftPad = (maxCellLength - longestDigit) / 2;

    int rightPad = maxCellLength - longestDigit - leftPad;

    String fmt = "|%" + leftPad +"s%" + longestDigit + "s%" + rightPad + "s"; //construct our string format

    String separator = "+" + repeat("-", maxCellLength); //construct the separator

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      // This will resize our row separator for each row
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        System.out.print(separator);
      }

      System.out.print("+\n");

      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        System.out.print(String.format(fmt, "", temp[i][j], ""));
      }

      System.out.print("|\n");
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      System.out.print(separator);
    }

    System.out.print("+\n");
  }


  public static int longestDigit(int[][] arr) {
    int longest = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        String intStr = String.valueOf(arr[i][j]);
        if (intStr.length() > longest) longest = intStr.length();
      }
    }

    return longest;
  }

  private static String repeat(String n, int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      sb.append(n);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to smart-ify my naive if-statements, lol +1

Comment: Updated my answer to add more dynamic calculations of the cell width along with the padding